# Tomcat JDBC configured on Server and included in Application WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, ojdbc

We are upgrading our Oracle database installation from 11g to 12c (12.2.0.1) and need to upgrade our OJDBC drivers.

We have tomcat servers running with OJDBC 6 drivers on the server configured in the sever.xml.

We have OJDBC 8 drivers included with in the application WAR file.

Will the application use connection pools created by the Tomcat/OJDBC 6 drivers or will the drivers packaged with the application's WAR take precedence?

Update:

I've been told it's **possible** to have the Tomcat load an OJDBC driver on startup (classpath in our configuration).   However, poorly written Applications can inadvertently open Oracle connections using a bundled driver.   I've researched this but have not found a definitive answer.  Has anyone encountered this situation or know if it's even possible?

Comment: The ones on the servers classpath will be loaded first. So those are the ones you will get.

Comment: WildFly / JBoss have a [modular classloader](https://github.com/jboss-modules/jboss-modules) so that you can change that behavior, but every other app server I know of has that limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html),

"from the perspective of a web application, class or resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:
Bootstrap classes of your JVM
/WEB-INF/classes of your web application
/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
System class loader classes (described above)
Common class loader classes (described above)
If the web application class loader is configured with  then the order becomes:
Bootstrap classes of your JVM
System class loader classes (described above)
Common class loader classes (described above)
/WEB-INF/classes of your web application
/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application*
".

You want to use the advanced  class loader configuration